# Why all caps first and last names in id cards / passports?

Tags: california, france, passport

I am wondernig what is the reason, if any, that in the national identification cards the **names** (first and last) are written in **ALL CAPS**?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The reason is, it's the law. The explanation is, majuscule is "basic", minuscule is a fancy add-on. Interpretation errors are reduced when majuscule is used, esp. in handwriting contexts.

Comment: @user6726 is it the law though?  I don't see anything about this in the laws of New York, for example.

Comment: I think this is a question about standards rather than the law. I don't think there is a law (not in the UK, anyway) that says "names in passports must be in capital letters".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is extremely diverse globally and not about the **law**: While there are international treaties about how an international ID, passport or drivers license has to look, to some degree, the actual look is defined in national regulations. There's not even a law about the look usually!

Comment: Also all capital letters in English are the same height and go from the bottom line to the top line. Some lower case go below and there are different heights. I have no idea what they do in France about c cedilla, accent ague, accent grave, etc.

Comment: @Trish Then isn't that the answer? I think just because the answer is "The law doesn't govern this" doesn't mean it doesn't belong here, esp. if the question is about whether the law governs something.

Comment: @Andrew no, the question is not about law. It's about international politics. International treaties are **Politics-SE** not Law.

Comment: @Trish International treaties aren't law?! Man, I wish I had known that before I took those classes in law school. Also, like half the legal work I do daily is governed by international treaties. Yes, International Treaties are appropriate for Law.SE.

Comment: @Andrew  ICAO Document 9303,  ISO/IEC 14443 and  ISO/IEC 7501-1 are **not** laws, they are norms or standards. The relevant laws that make the countries obey these standards are not international. The passport standards are not even treaties in some sense!

Comment: @Trish I never said those were Treaties? Treaties are on topic for Law.SE.

Comment: @Andrew This is a case of the mentioned documents, NOT a law or treaty. Which makes this question Off Topic.

Comment: @Trish then that is the answer. Just because an answer is that something is not governed by a law does not make it inappropriate for Law.SE if the question is about the law. Those mentioned documents do not appear in the question. If those docs answer the question, then make them an answer and note that there is not a law governing.

Comment: @Trish whether something is governed by an international treaty is certainly on topic here.  Many countries regard international treaties as having force of law.  Furthermore, international treaties form the basis of international law.  Furthermore, either ICAO documents don't specify upper or lower case for the visual inspection zone or some countries are not compliant with ICAO, because not all countries use upper case (that is, the premise of the question is incorrect).

Comment: @Andrew the actual answer is that the premise of the question is flawed.  There are countries that do not use all caps in passports and ID cards.  Anyone looking for a law, treaty, or standard that requires them to do so is going to search in vain.

Comment: The *scope* of the question is unclear. Another case for mandatory specification of jurisdiction.

Answer (score 3):

Some jurisdictions do that.  Others don't (see, for example, the [Dutch national identity card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_identity_card)).

My New York driver's license is in all caps, and I rather suspect that it's a holdover from the days in which licenses were processed using a computer system that had only upper-case characters.

But that's just a guess.  The real answer is that the premise of the question is incorrect.

Comment: Another reason is that case sensitive database entries are more likely to produce false negative results in a search for a name, while is a much more serious problem in the circumstances in which it is usually used, than a false positive result, from the perspective of the government establishing the database.

Answer (score 2):

The League of Nations Passport Conference of 1926 contained **suggestions** on how christan and surnames should be written:

> **Annex**
> *Various Entries.*.
> The question of the entries to be made on the passport form has given rise to the following observations:
>
> 1. Sufficient space should be provided for the full name of the holder;
> 2. Christian names and surnames should be written either in block capitals or in what is known as English roundhand;
> 3. The surname should be underlined.
>
> It is agreed that christian names need not be translated.

United States Passports that I have seen, never underlined the surnames. Other countries often did. Sometimes spaces between the letters of the surname were used instead of underlining.

With the introduction of typewritten passports, in the United States since 1931-01-02, all entries were mostly uppercase.

[image]

**Note**: The typed letters are red. A passport issued in September 1931 (and later) are black.

A 1934 passport of Moritz Feibusch, which was retrieved from the ruins of the Hindenburg, can be seen here:

- [Moritz Feibusch and the Hindenburg](https://www.flickr.com/photos/magnesmuseum/albums/72157624208880791)

---

**Sources**:

- [The United States passport: past, present, future, Issue 153 by United States. Passport Office. 1976](https://books.google.co.ao/books/download/The_United_States_passport.pdf?id=YtaPAAAAMAAJ&hl=pt-PT&output=pdf&sig=ACfU3U3f5VW9pf3K-1ABSexqG5UeyeNt8Q) (PDF)

Comment: FYI. The terminology "Christian name" used in 1926 is now outdated and has largely been superseded by the terminology "Given name" that lacks a religious affiliation (the term "Christian name" in the context of passports, when a majority of people in the word are not Christian, illustrates why the old terminology is problematic).

Comment: @ohwilleke To be politicaly correct it should be meantioned the use of 'Christian name' is particular to the **English** language, in the French (Prénome), German (Vorname), Italian (Nome) languages, have through out the 20th (even the 19th as far as I can tell) century, used a term that lacks a religious affiliation in their documents.

Answer (score 0):

> In the national identification cards the names (first and last) are written in ALL CAPS

That's incorrect, another example is [Thai identity cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_identity_card), which don't use all caps.

[image]

([image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suchanannakmai.com%2F&psig=AOvVaw3KVF06KgxNhcZg2eSlabyL&ust=1592941864938000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCOi88IeZluoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD))

Comment: Maybe because her *real* name is written in Thai ("Nikmai" in Thai is "นาคใหม่" that you find above "Suchanan"), and it's a Thai ID card. On a passeport, international document, it's probably all caps for her last name, at least.